# Installing PostGIS on Windows

Tags: postgis, installation, windows

I want to create an application platform based on PostGIS data. I read the documentation where I saw the prerequisite to install GEOS, GDAL and Proj4. The main problem is I am using windows platform.

Can anybody refer me where I can get full documentation on how to install PostGIS, GDAL, GEOS, Proj4 on Windows with all their libraries?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have to worry about any of those prerequisites when installing PostGIS on Windows. You just need to install the [Postgresql installer for your platform](http://www.postgresql.org/download/). You can then launch the Application Stack Builder to install PostGIS.

[image]

[image]

You can find more detailed installation instructions at the [Boston GIS web site](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @pateto777 answer and other sources like [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgsqlportable/) , I managed to have a "portable" installation of PostGIS on a windows 7 machine without admin rights.

1. Select the packages and download the binaries zip files.
   I went for:

   - postgresql-9.6.3-3-windows-x64-binaries.zip
   - postgis-bundle-pg96-2.3.3x64.zip
2. Unzip the content in a merged folder, I used "pgsql", so within this folder you will have the folders: bin, doc, gdal-data, include, lib, pgAdmin 4, share, utils, symbols and utils. No "data" folder yet!
3. Create a cluster before using it. I used a batch file in the merged folder to create it. I called FirstBatch.bat

> @ECHO ON
> REM The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL
> @SET PATH="%~dp0bin";%PATH%
> @SET PGDATA=%~dp0data
> @SET PGDATABASE=postgres
> @SET PGUSER=postgres
> @SET PGPORT=5439
> @SET PGLOCALEDIR=%~dp0share\locale
> "%~dp0bin\initdb" -U postgres -A trust -E utf8
> ECHO "Click enter to exit"
> pause

4. Start postgresql. I used a batch file in the merged folder to start it. It has to be running while you want to access the database. I called NormalBatch.bat.

> @ECHO ON
>     REM The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL
>     @SET PATH="%~dp0\bin";%PATH%
>     @SET PGDATA=%~dp0\data
>     @SET PGDATABASE=geodb
>     @SET PGUSER=postgres
>     @SET PGPORT=5439
>     @SET PGLOCALEDIR=%~dp0\share\locale
>     "%~dp0bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0data" -l logfile start
>     ECHO "Click enter to stop"
>     pause
>     "%~dp0\bin\pg_ctl" -D "%~dp0/data" stop

5. While the previous batch is running, create a geodatabase called "geodb". I used this batch to connect to the shell

> REM shell interface
> "%~dp0bin\psql" -p 5439 -U postgres

then type:

```
postgres=#create database geodb;
postgres=#\connect geodb;
geodb=#CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
geodb=#CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
geodb=#\q
```

Voilà! A postGIS database called `geodb` is available for user `postgres` on port `5439`

Answer (score 5):

you can check out [Portable GIS V3](http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/2012/09/12/portable-gis-v3-released/) which is newly released. the package contains what you need about GIS.

- Desktop GIS packages QGIS (with GRASS plugin) version 1.8
- FWTools (GDAL and OGR toolkit)
- Apache2 and Php5
- PostgreSQL (version 9.0)/Postgis (version 1.5)
- Mapserver 5.6 and 6, OpenLayers.
- Python 2.7
- Loader- for loading gml such as Ordnance Survey Mastermap into a PostgreSQL Database
- Utilities- portable firefox, pdf reader and text editor

[image: port]

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 5):

If you like the manual installations, you can follow these steps:

1. Downloaded the binary files. In my case I used:

   postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows-x64-binaries.zip

   postgis-bundle-pg95-2.2.2x64-2.zip
2. Copy all the content from postgis to postgresql in the root folder. At the end you will find the folders: bin, gdal-data, lib, pgAdmin III, share, utils and more files.
3. Assuming Postgres is already installed, connect to the shell and type:

   create database geodb;

   \connect geodb;

   CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

   CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;

These 2 extensions are enough for working.

Comment: `geodb=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` returns `ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in`

Answer (score 4):

I think R.K. answer is all you need, but if helps, I wrote a blog posts about installing and configuring PostGIS Raster on Windows

EDIT: I forgot to renew the domain and now it points to a porn site. Sorry for the inconvenience :-(

Comment: The link in this answer took me to a porn site. Beware.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for reporting it. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would provide an update as the earlier user guides are a bit out of date.

I used a combination of the website from @Hani Dradi which really helped with the PostgreSQL installation and a second website as I was not sure what applications I should install with PostgreSQL using Stack Builder - the answer was only PostGIS.

https://www.geo-gate.com/docs/gis-environment-installation/installing-postgresql/
https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/postgresql/

Also note that pgAdmin now runs in the browser
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435656/pgadmin-4-always-open-in-browser-not-as-a-standalone-desktop-application

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.geo-gate.com/docs/gis-environment-installation/installing-postgresql/) outlines screenshots for installing PostgreSQL and PostGIS