# How to build a Spatialite road network from OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, spatialite, network, graph

I'm looking for algorithm which could help me with building my own road network (for routing) from OSM data.

*I chose Spatialite DB for this, but here I have only one problem: Spatialite provides interface for build road network, but prepared road graph is saved in BLOBS so I can't get any information about it (of course, I can write queries to DB for routing facilities) but I want to draw all links on my map, so I need to get their coordinates.*

Actually, I'm not sure if Spatialite could provide such API or smith like that.

My question is how can I build my own road graph (network) from raw OSM data (I've already parsed XML file for highways=*) ?

Comment: You would find it beneficial to use postGIS and postgres with pgrouting. example  http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/

Comment: @Mapperz yes, but using Postgres assumes working with "not-lite" SQL DB. In my opinion sqlite is better as it doesn't need server for working.

Comment: Postgis does not need a server - it can run locally on a pc without issue. It can even be portable http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/how-to-install-postgis-on-windows

Comment: Extracting the coordinates shouldn't be a problem - you already have them (after all, you put them into the database at the start). What is the particular issue - writing the query, the wrong format, or something else?

Comment: @BradHard Actually I don't understand how to define junctions(links) throw all this data. My first idea was that all ways could be used as the arcs of graph. But I'm not sure if they doesn't consist links inside them. I mean that in <way> first and last nodes always links and only they, whereas other nodes mentioned in this <way> is used only for geometry of they way.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The first and the last node don't have to be links, the way can have one or even two open ends. Furthermore *every* node in the way can be part of one or more other ways, thus creating a junction. This is not limited to the first and last node.

Comment: Have you seen the tools and samples at https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=OSM+tools ? That should allow you to extract what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use our free converter for changing OSM into a routable network, that splits at all intersections. This means OSM ways are changed into multiple links. Input is OSM XML files, output is for instance SHP. Find it at www.routeware.dk, download section.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May be it will suit me) But anyway how did you recognize all junctions/links ?

Comment: Basically you keep track of how many times a node is shared between ways. If more than one time, then the node is candidate for a split. Requires reading all ways twice.