# Can QGIS open a SDF file created by HEC RAS?

Tags: qgis, hec-ras, sdf

I used the "export GIS data" option in [HEC RAS](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/) and got a [SDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_data_file) file.

Is it possible to open it in QGIS?

Comment: The SDF file generated by HEC-RAS can be read by the HEC-GeoRAS extension for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

i tried to do that, but apparently arcgis is needed to read .sdf format. Anyway I have an alternative to export the flooding surfaces to Qgis, but it's not the best way.

1. In HEC-RAS after you have your results, go to View-XYZPerspective
   plots.
2. Copy the image to a image editor and save it as png, or another
   image format.
3. In QGIS go to Raster-Georeferencerer-Georeferencerer...
4. Import the image and use the tool to georeference matching the cross
   sections (I had the cross sections in QGIS and then I exported to
   HEC-RAS as it says in the link [Is it possible to export cross sections from QGIS to HEC-RAS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91750/is-it-possible-to-export-cross-sections-from-qgis-to-hec-ras)).

Then you will have the surfaces in QGIS!.

I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to do that, but in my case it was a good solution. To do that I import the cross sections in UTM coordinate system.

Comment: arcgis does not support sdf, it is only used by autocad-map and mapguide.

Comment: hec-georas with arcgis?