# Create extension PostGIS throws unknown error 193

Tags: postgis, postgresql, windows

I have execute all actions like this
[How to install PostGIS on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/how-to-install-postgis-on-windows/265223#265223).
But when I `create extension postgis;`

I have got an error message :

> "PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.dll » : unknown error 193".

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you recently upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download PostGIS from? Did you download the 32 or 64 bit version? This seems to have resulted before on Windows from a user using a 32 bit PostGIS, with 64 bit libraries.

https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3381